# Negative fitted curve extrapolation

Tags: python, dataframe, extrapolation, best-fit-curve

Good day, I am currently working with a set of data imported from a csv file.  I have y values and x values (See image attached) that I am trying to extrapolate (to Age 100) and plot on a plane.  My problem however, is that each polynomial fit function causes the curve to shoot negative or positive when it should be just a decay function, thus I have resorted to a decay function.  I need to determine the best polyfit function.  How would I go about dealing with these extremely negative values gained by the fit function?  Thanks for the help in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Read the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
V_Class_EC = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_EC.csv')
V_Class_FS = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_FS.csv')
V_Class_GP = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_GP.csv')
V_Class_L = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_L.csv')
V_Class_MP = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_MP.csv')
V_Class_NC = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_NC.csv')
V_Class_NW = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_NW.csv')
V_Class_WP = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_WP.csv')
V_Class_ZN = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\V_Class_ZN.csv')
VKT_BY_AGE = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\VKT_BY_AGE.csv')
EMISSIONS_BY_VEHICLE_TYPE = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\EMMISIONS_BY_VEHICLE_TYPE.csv')
EMISSION_FACTOR_OVER_AGE = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\EMMISION_FACTOR_OVER_AGE.csv')
EMISSION_VEHICLE_SPEED_CO = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\EMMISION+VEHICLE_SPEED_CO.csv')
EMISION_VEHICLE_SPEED_NOx = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\leone\OneDrive\Desktop\Year_4\Sem2\REII425\Data\EMMISION+VEHICLE_SPEED_NOx.csv')


# Replace NaN values with 0
V_Class_EC.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_FS.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_GP.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_L.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_MP.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_NC.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_NW.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_WP.fillna(0, inplace=True)
V_Class_ZN.fillna(0, inplace=True)
VKT_BY_AGE.fillna(0, inplace=True)
EMISSIONS_BY_VEHICLE_TYPE.fillna(0, inplace=True)
EMISSION_FACTOR_OVER_AGE.fillna(0, inplace=True)
EMISSION_VEHICLE_SPEED_CO.fillna(0, inplace=True)
EMISION_VEHICLE_SPEED_NOx.fillna(0, inplace=True)

V_Class_EC = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_EC)
V_Class_FS = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_FS)
V_Class_GP = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_GP)
V_Class_L = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_L)
V_Class_MP = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_MP)
V_Class_NC = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_NC)
V_Class_NW = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_NW)
V_Class_WP = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_WP)
V_Class_ZN = pd.DataFrame(V_Class_ZN)
VKT_BY_AGE = pd.DataFrame(VKT_BY_AGE)
EMISSIONS_BY_VEHICLE_TYPE = pd.DataFrame(EMISSIONS_BY_VEHICLE_TYPE)
EMISSION_FACTOR_OVER_AGE = pd.DataFrame(EMISSION_FACTOR_OVER_AGE)
EMISSION_VEHICLE_SPEED_CO = pd.DataFrame(EMISSION_VEHICLE_SPEED_CO)
EMISION_VEHICLE_SPEED_NOx = pd.DataFrame(EMISION_VEHICLE_SPEED_NOx)

Age_range = np.arange(1,101)


def decay_curve(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c * np.exp(-d * x)

Age = VKT_BY_AGE['Age']
LDPV_private = VKT_BY_AGE['LDPV (private car)']
LDPV_taxi = VKT_BY_AGE['LDPV (taxi)']
LDPV_non_commercial = VKT_BY_AGE['HDPV (non-commercial)']
HDPV_bus = VKT_BY_AGE['HDPV (bus)']
LDT = VKT_BY_AGE['LDT']
HDT = VKT_BY_AGE['HDT']

coefficients, _ = curve_fit(decay_curve, Age, LDPV_private)
#fitted_curve = np.poly1d(coefficients)

LDPV_private_extended = decay_curve(Age_range, *coefficients)
plt.plot(Age, LDPV_private, 'o')
plt.plot(Age_range, LDPV_private_extended, '-', label='LDPV_private Data')
plt.show()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('LDPV_private')
plt.title('LDPV_private Data Plot')



#print(VKT_BY_AGE)
```

[image]